# Change iframe content within an element

Tags: jquery, iframe

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step12").html('');
    $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step12").html('11');
    $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step13").html('');
    $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step13").html('12');
    $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step14").html('');
    $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step14").html('13');
    $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step15").html('');
    $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step15").html('14');
});
```

I try to use the above code to change the content in an iframe, but it is not working. Unless I put `alert('');` on top of `$('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step12").html('');`

if just will take effect. What is the reason for that, anyone could help?

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/ZkWLz/

Comment: Did you verify the length of the selector is 1+ and not 0... ?

Comment: My side cannot work. I put my iframe content such like this
<iframe id="keywordframe" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/ff/rr/<?php echo $id; ?>" width="570" height="230" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
is it the reason cause it cannot work properly?

Comment: reply to gordan: I dind't put in cos every html sure has its own value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could just be that you need to wait for the iframe to load.

Since this is the only thing I can think of at this time, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#keywordframe').load(function() {
        $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step12").html('');
        $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step12").html('11');
        $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step13").html('');
        $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step13").html('12');
        $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step14").html('');
        $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step14").html('13');
        $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step15").html('');
        $('#keywordframe').contents().find("#step15").html('14');
    });
});
```

Whether it will fix your problem or not I don't know, but it's worth a try.